# Cannot debug project with WcfTestClient in VS 2019

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2019

After reinstal win 10 I installed VS 2019 (used VS 2013 before). All is running well, only one project with svc service I can't debug using WcfTextClient. Build is OK, but when the WcfTestClient appears, an excption occurs: FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
I'm afraid it's because the version of MSBulid according to VS 2019 is 16.8.1. But I can't discover, where it is configured that ver 15.1.0.0. is required. Tried to change relative paths in devenv.exe.config and WcfTestClient.exe.config, with no effect. The project is configured to target framework 4.5.2. If I start debugging in an aspx page (without WcfTestClient), it works fine. If I try it on another machine with both VS 2013 and VS 2019 installed it works also in VS 2019 there.

The project is set with

```
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

The required version 15.1.0.0 refers to VS 2017 which I have never installed on my machine.
I tried to change the version and path to the file in all possible configs found under IDE directory of VS, no success.
Then I tried to install vs_buildtools for VS 2017, didn't help (but it is actualy version 15.9).
Finally I've installed MSBuild 15.1, also v12.0, but the error is still the same.

Comment: Hi, May I know how is the issue going on now? If you do not have any other concerns, please remember to mark the answer.

Comment: I had to postpone this, but now I've installed MSBuild 12, also didn't help. But I think the question is, why the version 15.1. is required, it shoud not.

Comment: You can try to find the Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core installation package in the nuget package and install it.

Comment: I think I have it, I can find Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll at c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\.

Comment: It needs to be confirmed to be installed in the project so that the project can use this nuget package.

Comment: Into the project I can't install 15+ versions because of target framework (see the error in previos comment). I tried to install 14.3 (latest possible) and didn't help. But I believe the missing file is not required by the project, but by the wcfTestClient itself. So I tried to install older version of WcfTestClient, run it and it can connect to the running wcf service. So that's the trick for me. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

According to the error message, the version=15.1.0.0 msbuild tool should be missing, and the project is created by it. Below are the different versions of msbuild owned by vs and the location of the msbuild.

[image]

You can download different versions of msbuild here:[msbuild](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/releases?after=v15.8.168.64424).

You can find Nuget package manager in the tool options, and then select manage nuget packge for solution. In this interface, you can install Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.[image]

Comment: Thank you, it's much more clear now. Is it possible to convert the project and force it to use current msbuild (even if it is not possilble to build it in vs 2013 any more).

Comment: I'm not sure that the missing tool is required by the project, as the project itself can be built and ran. Only if WcfTestClient starts the tool is missing.

Comment: If you can use it on the machine where vs 2013 and vs 2019 are installed, you can try to install the 12.0 version of msbuild.

Comment: v12 didn't help. Tried to install v 15.1 (as VS_build tools for VS 2017 gave the latest version 15.9), but installation failed with error: Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.Build 15.1.1013'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files
 that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: Now I installed the 15.1 (thru new empty project based on 4.6 framework, so the installation secceeded). But no success with my issue.